# Proving that a sequence is increasing

Tags: sequences-and-series

**Problem:** A sequence $(a_n)$ is defined recursively as follows, where $0<\alpha\leqslant 2$:
$$
a_1=\alpha,\quad a_{n+1}=\frac{6(1+a_n)}{7+a_n}.
$$
Prove that this sequence is increasing and bounded above by $2$. What is its limit?

---

**Ideas:** How should I go about starting this proof? If the value of $a_1$ were given, I could show numerically and by induction that the sequence is increasing. But no exact value of $\alpha$ is given.

Comment: Just simply assume you "know" the $\alpha$ value.

Comment: Are you implying that I should suppose that the sequence is increasing?

Comment: No, I'm saying that the value of $\alpha$ is irrelevant.

Comment: A little more hint would be helpful.
If I want to prove that this sequence is increasing then each subsequence sequence must be greater than it's predecessors. This implies that the difference between each sequence must be positive.

Comment: You can prove boundedness with induction. You're given the bounds 0 and 2  for the first term. You can then induct and do some algebra.

For increasing, just consider $a_{n+1}-a_n$ and note the bounds from the first part.

Comment: I don't think I've ever seen a chosen answer at $-3$ with another answer provided at $+6$. Fascinating.

Comment: That was probably the best answer at that point in time. Beliefs changes in accordance to the evidences on hand.

Comment: @science What advice did I give? Also, downvotes do mean things in general. They can trigger system flags, they communicate a worthless or flawed answer, etc. They're *not* for nothing.

Comment: Guys, I really appreciate all the help on this site. @science has helped me with my topics for a fair bit and I think this site helped me learn on an order of a few magnitudes more than what lecturers are paid to do.

Comment: *science*'s answer is completely incorrect, and *Nathanson* had already pointed out a counter-example in his comment. Besides learning to solve math questions, you also need to learn to ascertain the correctness of any answer in general, otherwise you will never know for sure what is correct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, $0\leq a_1\leq2$.

Second, $a_{n+1}=\frac{6(1+a_n)}{7+a_n}=6-\frac{36}{7+a_n}$.

So, if $0\leq a_n\leq2$,

$\qquad$then $7\leq 7+a_n\leq 9$,

$\qquad$then $\frac{1}{7}\geq\frac{1}{7+a_n}\geq\frac{1}{9}$,

$\qquad$then $\frac{36}{7}\geq\frac{36}{7+a_n}\geq\frac{36}{9}$,

$\qquad$then $-\frac{36}{7}\leq-\frac{36}{7+a_n}\leq-\frac{36}{9}$,

$\qquad$then $0\leq6-\frac{36}{7}\leq6-\frac{36}{7+a_n}\leq6-\frac{36}{9}=2$,

then $0\leq a_{n+1}\leq2$.

By induction $0\leq a_n\leq2$ for all $n$.

Also $a_{n+1}-a_n=\frac{6(1+a_n)}{7+a_n}-a_n=\frac{6-a_n-a_n^2}{7+a_n}=\frac{(a_n+3)(2-a_n)}{7+a_n}>0$, as long as $0\leq a_n\leq2$.

Therefore $a_{n+1}\geq a_n$.

Comment: Cleaner than what I had wrote. +1 :) Also, I had a small hole in my writing now that I think about it...

Comment: I'm having a hard time coming to terms with "if 0 <= a_n<=2".

Comment: @guest: If you have a hard time with that, then you should go and relearn induction. *Nathanson*'s proof above shows that we can do the following. First $a_1 \in [0,2]$. Then since we can prove that $a_2 \in [0,2]$ if we are given $a_1 \in [0,2]$, we can conclude that indeed  $a_2 \in [0,2]$. But we also can prove that $a_3 \in [0,2]$ if we are given $a_2 \in [0,2]$. So we can conclude that $a_3 \in [0,2]$. Clearly we can repeat this any number of times in principle, that is, if you tell me a fixed natural number $n$, I can repeat the above argument $n-1$ times to prove that $a_n \in [0,2]$.

Comment: @guest: But this reasoning depends on one crucial assumption, that we can actually repeat the above argument **as many times as we want**. It for example ignores the fact that we will run out of breath/paper/life. But if we do ignore that, then we can claim that by an axiom called the axiom of induction that $a_n \in [0,2]$ for every natural number $n$, since we have at least shown that we have a way to produce a proof for any particular $n$ one may desire.

Comment: @guest: One more thing, note that you should not be having a hard time with that particular line regardless of whether you understand induction, because *Nathanson* is stating something that is simply true, namely that **if it is true that** $a_n \in [0,2]$, **then it is also true that $a_{n+1} \in [0,2]$. He proved this conditional assertion correct, and it has nothing to do with whether $a_n \in [0,2]$ is really true or not.

Comment: @user21820 I will be looking through what has been posted. Perhaps "hard time" was a poor choice of words. I suspect there's some discomfort with induction in the sense of it not being as convincing as I hope for it to be-unsatisfying if I may.

Comment: @guest: Do you agree with the conditional statement proven above? If not, then your issue is with conditionals. If you do, then your issue is with induction, in which case what you can do is to explicitly use the proven conditional statement to prove $a_2 \in [0,2]$ by substituting $n=1$, and then substituting $n=2$ to prove $a_3 \in [0,2]$, and repeating it explicitly as many times as you wish. If you are still not convinced, it could be that you doubt that we could reach all natural numbers by repeatedly adding 1, but natural numbers are in fact defined to be only those obtainable that way.

Answer (score -3):

To prove the sequence is increasing consider the function

$$ f(x) = \frac{6(1+x)}{7+x}$$

and prove $f'(x)>0$ for $x>0$. To find the limit assume the limit is $a=\lim_{n\to \infty} a_n $ which gives

$$ a = \frac{6(1+a)}{7+a} $$

and solve for $a$.

I leave it for you to prove boundedness.

Comment: What's the down vote for?

Comment: I see why derivative is employed. But I'd like to do it without differentiation.
Edit: I did not down vote.

Comment: If $g(x)=x/2$, then $g'(x)=1/2>0$, but $a_1=1$, $a_{n+1}=g(a_n)=a_n/2$ is a decreasing sequence.

Comment: @avid19 : Of course you can consider this function and use the first derivative test. I am asking you not to rush and down vote answers.

Comment: Your answer is simply incorrect, as Nathanson points out a counterexample. I didn't rush and downvote, I downvoted you because your answer is plainly wrong.

Comment: @guest: Your question says prove it is increasing and does not specify the technique. So this answer is a correct answer. Try to prove it is increasing in another way.

Comment: @science: A function $f$ can be increasing in its domain of definition, but yet fail to satisfy the inequality $f(x)>x$ everywhere. Leaving it to you as an exercise to find examples of such functions. Anyway, with recursive definition $a_{n+1}=f(a_n)$ you need $f(x)>x$ to conclude that the sequence is increasing. So I join in your critics.

Comment: @avid19: It is possible to prove that you get an increasing sequence by using derivatives. It is most likely not needed, and not the intended way. Exercises like this appear in my freshman course well before continuity, let alone differentiability, of a function is introduced. Anyway, the answerer is going about it in a wrong way.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I'm well aware differentiability is not an intended technique since this is a chapter that comes before differentiability. The solution I have on hand is making a alot of "supposition that the sequence is an increasing sequence which leaves much to be desired.

Comment: @Jyrki Lahtonen It's something you have to be very precise about, but yes you are correct. I wrote my criticism wrong.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen: and Downvoters: You are attacking one part of the answer which according to your comments is wrong! You could've left comments without three downvotes and we could fix things if there was something wrong.

Comment: You need to properly read what is written in your link. The condition is written for $a_n=f(n)$, not for $a_{n+1}=f(a_n)$.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen: Is this a necessary condition (in your comment) or a sufficient condition for the a sequence to to be increasing? I leave this as an exercise for you to figure out.